# When using SLSQP for minima, changes in the order of the constraints can lead to changes in the results

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am solving a minimum problem using SciPy

When using `SLSQP` for minima, changes in the order of the constraints can lead to changes in the result

The following is my code, I found that as long as the order of `constraint1` to `constraint5` in `cons` is disturbed, the result will change (the range will not be very large)

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def objective(x):
    return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 + x[2]**2 + x[3]**2 + x[4]**2
def constraint1(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] + x[2] - 1

def constraint2(x):
    return x[0] - x[1] + x[3] - 2

def constraint3(x):
    return x[2] + x[4] - 3

def constraint4(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] - x[2] - 4

def constraint5(x):
    return x[3] + x[4] - 5

x0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint3},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint4},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint5}]

result = minimize(objective, x0, constraints=cons)
```

Is it an algorithm problem or a code problem? If I still want to use the `SLSQP` algorithm, can I keep the result unchanged?

I hope that the results that can use SLSQP will not change all the time

Answer (score 1):

Your objective is just a self-dot product so write it as such. Add the Jacobian - it's a very simple one. And don't make your constraints callables - express them as linear constraints. This produces an objective of 26.95833333 regardless of the row order.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint


def objective(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return x.dot(x)


def jacobian(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return 2*x


A = np.array((
    (1,  1,  1,  0,  0),
    (1, -1,  0,  1,  0),
    (0,  0,  1,  0,  1),
    (1,  1, -1,  0,  0),
    (0,  0,  0,  1,  1),
))
lb = (1,      2,      3,      4,      5)
ub = (1, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf)

result = minimize(
    fun=objective, jac=jacobian,
    x0=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    constraints=(
        # A warning is raised unless these are separated
        LinearConstraint(A=A[:1, :], lb=lb[:1], ub=ub[:1]),
        LinearConstraint(A=A[1:, :], lb=lb[1:], ub=ub[1:]),
    ),
)
assert result.success, result.message
print('obj =', result.fun)
print('x =', result.x)
print('Constraints =', A @ result.x)
```

```
obj = 26.95833333333353
x = [ 1.91666667  0.58333333 -1.5         0.66666667  4.5       ]
Constraints = [1.         2.         3.         4.         5.16666667]
```